# expand a polygon region in a matrix

Tags: matlab, convex-polygon

I have the following matrix:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 2 2 2 1 1 3
1 1 2 2 2 2 1 3
1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I want to expand the region of value 2 by size 1, which means after expansion, the output is:

```
1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 
1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3
1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1
```

I think imerode can expand and shrink for binary image, while is not applicable in this case. Is there any methods in matlab can solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**One-Liner Solution**

Use:

```
mat(imdilate(mat==2,strel('disk',2)))=2;
```

**Result**

```
mat =

 1     1     2     2     2     1     1     1
 1     2     2     2     2     2     1     1
 2     2     2     2     2     2     2     3
 2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
 1     2     2     2     2     2     2     3
 1     1     2     2     2     2     1     1
```

**Step By Step explanation**

The solution for this problem is based on [dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)) operation on the the areas in which the matrix is equal to 2. 
This can be done as follow:

```
%initializes the input matrix
mat = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ; 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1; 1,1,2,2,2,1,1,3 ; 1,1,2,2,2,2,1,3; 1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3 ; 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];

%initilizes a mask which represents the reion which we want to exapand
roiMask = mat==2;

%perform expansion to this mask by imdilate function
dilatedRoi = imdilate(mat==2,strel('disk',2));

%assigns the new value into the original matrix
mat(dilatedRoi) = 2;
```

Notice that the dilation operation is characterized by a structuring element object, which is basically a binary matrix which defines the way to perform the expansion.
In my example, I used MATLAB's strel function, which generates the following:

```
strel('disk',2)

ans = 
 0     0     1     0     0
 0     1     1     1     0
 1     1     1     1     1
 0     1     1     1     0
 0     0     1     0     0
```

You may want to change the strel in order to fully control the desired expansion behavior.